Hugo 0.140 makes newline of linebreak
I've just upgraded to a newer version of Hugo (0.140), and the behavior has changed from what it was previously. Now for every linebreak I have in my posts/pages, it creates a linebreak in the generated HTML as well. This is different compared to for example GitHub markdown, where a linebreak doesn't create a linebreak in the generated page. It's also different to the behavior of the older versions of Hugo.
Is it possible to revert this behavior, so that a linebreak in the code doesn't cause a linebreak in the generated pages?

Why not ask this on hugo's bug tracker instead?

Because maybe they've defined the default behavior and don't think it's a bug.
